# how to use on_ready from discord.py?

Tags: python, api, discord

Hello I have trouble using the API discord.py, I try to display in the console the message received, but every time the function on_reday returns no message.

```
#imports
import discord



TOKEN = "TOKEN"


client=discord.Client()






@client.event
async def on_message(message):
        
    try:
        print(message.content)
 
    except IndexError: #This IndexError is used to return when there is no Embed
        print("failure to read the message")
        return
        
    print(message.content)
    

client.run(TOKEN, bot=False)
```

Comment: Im sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. Do you want the bot to say some message when the bot is ready? The `on_ready` event doesnt take in any message

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online,
                                 activity=discord.Game("?help"))
    print("Bot is ready")
```

this will print ready when the bot will be online, it will change the  status and it will put the bot game(For me, it is ?help)
and import: from discord.ext import commands